# Can't control-drag to the exit icon

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, interface-builder

I'm using xcode 4.6.3.  I'm creating an iPad add and have created a storyboard with about 10 views on it. I've got segue's between them to link them up appropriately.

I've been able to create unwind segue's by control-dragging to the Exit icon in the past.  For some reason, after a few changes, I can't seem to get the Exit icon to highlight when I try and control-drag to it.

Does anyone have an idea why this is a problem ?  Is there something in my code to turn that would turn off this ability?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: You're trying to control-drag something on an iPad?

Comment: @Kevin he's talking about building iPad interfaces.

Comment: @BergQuester I see, within interface builder/Xcode?